# How to order string data of LinkedList

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, linked-list

How can I order a LinkedList that includes string type `{a,c,d,b,b,d,c,a,c}`. After ordering the output should be like this `{c,c,c,a,a,d,d,b,b}`.
Also the complexity should be O(1*n).

Comment: What order is this following?

Comment: There is a string data in linledlist and they are {a,c,d,b,b,d,c,a,c}. Head node points to the first 'a' node in list. I need to group them and the output should be {c,c,c,a,a,d,d,b,b} with O(n) complexity.

Comment: Ok, but if your grouping them you can group the items in multiple ways. {a, a, b, b, c, c, c, d, d} is one way you could group all items, is this also considered a valid output?

Comment: If they just need to be grouped, why not transform the `List` into a `Map` of `List`s?

Comment: @NickParsons No, it is not valid. Output should be fixed as {c,c,c,a,a,d,d,b,b}.

Comment: @MTCoster it is not allowed for this work.

Comment: For the 3rd time asking, could you answer why this kind of grouping ? why not d,d,a,b,b,c,c,c or b,b,c,c,c,a,d,d , ... ? why you're variant ? because you need a rule to sort

Comment: What is that order derived from? You need to be able to define a function that takes any two items and determines which way round they should be ordered. I have a suspicion this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: This is for inventory managemant system. There are 4 type dataname a,b,c and d. Group sequence should be c,a,d,b respectively. This is a must !

Comment: @kaann45 why are u specifying a complexity?

Comment: Well, then your "dataname"s should be some kind of objects, with at least 2 properties, possibly named "name" and a number - "id","index" or "ordinal"... and you define both in some kind of config-file (you *could* hard-code it, but that is usually a bad idea) and sort by the number.

Comment: Hint: Grouping can be done in linear time (and space) - if you group first, you only need to sort the groups, if the number of groups is constant (4 in your example) sorting the groups takes constant time as it is independent of N and therefore O(1).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the groups/names/items are always four and always `c`, `a`, `d` and `b`. Under this assumption it is easy: Create four lists, one for the `c` items, one for the `a` items, etc. Traverse your linked list; for each item append it to the appropriate new list. You may use `switch` on the strings. Finally append the four new lists in the right order.

This will take O(n) time and O(n) space.

If for some reason (I don’t know what it could be) you don’t want to create four lists, just keep four references to the four places in the sorted list where the `c`, `a`, `d` and `b` items should be inserted. This will require a decision about where to point as long as not all four names are in the list yet, though.

Comment: Thank you! So, How can I solve this problem on single LinkedList (without creating 4 linkedlist)? Which sorting algorithm can I use?

Answer (score 1):

> This is for inventory managemant system. There are 4 type dataname
>   a,b,c and d

So, you need to add that in your post(also explain the scenario if possible).

**Algorithm**

- Since you said there are only 4 types of data, maintain 8 variables - 2 per type of data for nodes `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` as shown below.

> ```
> Node head_c = null,tail_c = null;
> Node head_a = null,tail_a = null;
> Node head_d = null,tail_d = null;
> Node head_b = null,tail_b = null;
> ```

- Now, iterate over the linked list and whenever you get a `c`, do like below.

> ```
> if(head_c == null){
>    head_c = current_node;
> }else{
>    tail_c.next = current_node;
> }
> tail_c = current_node;
> ```

- Do the same as above for other nodes `a`,`d`,`b` too. What we are trying to do here is basically creating 4 individual lists `c`,`a`,`d`,`b` separately using the **same**(same hashCode) nodes of the linked list.
- Now, as you might have understood, all have to do is assigning one's tail to another list's head for each of the lists. See below.

> ```
> main_head = head_c;
> tail_c.next = head_a;
> tail_a.next = head_d;
> tail_d.next = head_b;
> tail_b.next = null;
> ```

- So, you got the grouping of `c`,`a`,`d`,`b` you need.
- Time Complexity- **O(n)** , Space Complexity is **O(1)**.

Comment: Thank you! So, How can I solve this problem on single LinkedList (without creating 4 linkedlist)? Which sorting algorithm can I use?

Comment: @kaann45 Those are 4 linked lists, but those are the nodes from your singly LinkedList itself. I am not creating 4 different new lists using `new` keyword.

Comment: @kaann45 You can think of this as a kind of `bucket sort` where each `type` of data represents a `bucket`.

Comment: I got stuck with the null pointer exception error. What could be the reason?

Comment: The problem is that: If there are 3 different data assign in the main loop to the Linked List and execute the printScreen method then pops a NullPointerException because of the this connection:main_head = head_c;
tail_c.next = head_a;
tail_a.next = head_d;
tail_d.next = head_b;
tail_b.next = null;. How I can avoid this because I want to print to the screen while there are less than 4 data type.

Comment: @kaann45 Can you edit your post and show us the code you're trying and your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, you can use `stream()`. Look the following code:

Sorting your data with this:

```
linkedList.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

or you can reverse sorted collection with this:

```
linkedList.stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: This would not be O(N), and it would sort in natural order instead of the specific one asked for in the question.